# Android - Camera, really tough task

Tags: android, camera, device

Is it possible to create an app to pass camera preview to another device?

I'm mean connect via USB to TV and show camera preview or like Ip Web Camera to the website.
Maybe connect by HDMI and using it as desktop PC?

Comment: You mean like Skype? Can you give a few more details about what it is that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, you will need to know all of the protocols of data transfer for every single device you wish to connect to (I don't know how many there are or if it is standardised). [View the documentation for USB data transfer and host applications.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html)

Examples:

Google **Android usb host turorial**. There are a ton.

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/11289-android-usb-host-tutorial-adbtest.html

http://resources.upverter.com/android-usb-accessory-mode

Comment: Do you know maybe any example? And it is something common with usb otg ?

Comment: @goodm refer to my edit.